# Why GCM server unregister my registration id even though I've not unregistered it from it?

Tags: android, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing the app which use `gcm registration` id.
But when i debug with one smartphone (Android version is 4.0.1), my app cannot receive completely a message.

I send a message from my website and my app is supposed to receive it.

My app can get `notification`, but call `onUnregistered` method.
And I cannot check the message.

I think that the gcm server unregister the registration id registered in my device.

I don't unregister registration id from gcm server.
And I have not uninstalled my app from this device.

Why gcm server `unregister` it?

What should I do to resolve this case?

Comment: I already checked that my app could register registration id in gcm server.

Comment: And I also know my device can get notifications of other apps.